# Networking up 3 pcs issue

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, routing

I'm feeling a bit stupid because this seemingly simple task is completely stumping me.

I have 3 PCs: Client, Gateway and Server.

Client needs to connect via Gateway to Server.

Both PCs are connected to gateway via crossover cables.

Static IPs have been given to each interface.

```
Client:eth1
ip : 192.168.138.1\24
gateway 192.168.138.254

Gateway eth4
ip 192.168.138.254\24
gateway 192.168.138.1

Gateway eth1
ip 192.168.137.254\24
gateway 192.168.137.1

Server eth0
ip 192.168.137.1\24
gateway 192.168.137.254
```

Client can ping Gateway eth4 and eth1, Server can ping Gateway eth4 and eth1 but Client cannot ping Server.

Gateway can ping everything.

At first I thought I needed to insert static routes on Client and Server but this did not help and I now think that as they can ping the Gateway interface on the other network it is not necessary?

Comment: More information on the nature of the gateway might be helpful. what kind of hardware/software (OS, etc.) is it? Do you have the interfaces bridged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you turned on IP routing?

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
1
```

If the output is '0', then you need to turn it on:

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Change the setting in `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make it persistent.

Comment: yep, it looks like the OP has not told the gateway OS to forward packages :-/

Answer (score 0):

So client1 hits its gateway at 138.254 that goes to 138.1 back to itself?...

Client:eth1 ip : 192.168.138.1\24  *
         gateway 192.168.138.254

Gateway eth4 ip 192.168.138.254\24
                gateway 192.168.138.1  *

Comment: this was supposed to be a question, not answer...sorry new here.

Comment: The big 'ask question' button up in the upper right is where to ask questions.